# Deploying large WAR files to JBoss AS 7

Tags: jboss

I am accessing my JBoss 7 web console via an HTTP proxy and am trying to upload a 21Mb WAR file. The Add Content function fails without an error message and see a 502 in my firebug window. On the Proxy I see

```
[Sat Mar 30 13:36:17 2013] [error] (103)Software caused connection abort: proxy: pass request body failed to <master-node-ip>:9990 (<master-node-ip>)
[Sat Mar 30 13:36:17 2013] [error] proxy: pass request body failed to <master-node-ip>:9990 (<master-node-ip>) from <broadband-ip> ()
```

Reading around the issue I find there is potentially a 5mb limit on the size of WARs uploaded via the web console. That makes a very easy to use console entirley useless for me - is there any work around?

Answer (score 1):

Set the maxPostSize parameter correctly in your /jboss-dir/conf/server.xml configuration file. You can see more details about that at http://docs.jboss.org/jbossweb/2.1.x/config/http.html.

With that said, if you are able to modify that configuration file then you're probably able to just drop the war into the appropriate directory for hot-deployment.

Comment: Does that apply to 7.1.1?

Comment: I believe so, JBoss config does not change all that dramatically. Did you try it?

Comment: Not yet, but looks to be slightly different http://docs.jboss.org/jbossweb/7.0.x/config/http.html